# How can I use the "ngx-doc-viewer" package in the vue 2 class style with typescript project?

Tags: vue-class-components

i want to use "ngx-doc-viewer" package in vue project. But i can not understand how to use this in vue 2 class style with typescirpt project .
Here is the link
[ngx-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-doc-viewer)
i am thinking about of how to use this NgxDocViewerModule module in vue.

Let me know if you can help me with this.
Thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to use an Angular module in Vue?

Comment: are there any package that can view any doc file in my website. Currently i am looking on google doc viewer as iframe can do this. Maybe this could help.

Comment: i find that "@accusoft/pdf-viewer" package can easily be used to show pdf file with very little code. Same way i want to show other files also.

Comment: Consider asking a question specific to solving your problem. Instead of "Let me know if you can help [...]", you could ask "How can I use the "ngx-doc-viewer" package in the vue 2 class style with typescript project?".